# Pattern to swap backslashes in particular quoted strings

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using sed (actually ssed with extended "-r", so I have access to most any regex functionality I might need) to process files, one change being to convert doubled backslash characters to a single forward slashes inside quoted strings.  The problem is that some quoted strings that contain the doubled backslashes should not be converted.  All quoted strings I want to target have a certain word "myPhrase" inside the quotes.

So for a file with these two lines:

```
"\\\\server\\dir\\myPhrase\\subdir"
"Don't change \\something me!"
```

the output would be:

```
"//server/dir/myPhrase/subdir"
"Don't change \\something me!"
```

I've tried various combinations of lookahead like (?=myPhrase) within a search pattern that finds the desired quoted chunks and replaces a capture group (\\) with / as the replacement, but all my attempts either replace just the first occurance of the doubled backslashes, or those to the left of myPhrase, etc.

I'm sure there is some combination of lookahead/noncapture/recursion that should do this, but I'm blanking out completely right now.

Comment: Did you try `sed '/myPhrase/ s/\\\\/\//g'`?

Comment: To use PCRE in ssed, you must use `-R` option, not `-r`. That is why lookarounds could not work.

Comment: Actually, `sed '/myPhrase/s,\\,/,g' file > newfile` should work for you. It will replace all ``\`` on a line that contains `myPhrase`

Comment: ssed `-R -e '/myPhrase/ s:\\\\:/:g;'` seems to do the trick for me.  It would fail if a line contained both a targeted quoted-string and one to be skipped, but hopefully I don't have that in my processing (I think I'm okay).  If I do, I'll take another crack at the lookarounds - I must have thought "ssed -r" got me PCRE features.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat file
"dont change \\this" "\\\\server\\dir\\myPhrase\\subdir" "nor\\this"
"Don't change \\something me!"

$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)("[^"]*myPhrase[^"]*")(.*)/,a){gsub(/[\\][\\]/,"/",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] a[3]} 1' file
"dont change \\this" "//server/dir/myPhrase/subdir" "nor\\this"
"Don't change \\something me!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution

```
perl -pe ' s{"(.+)?"}{$x=$1; if($x=~m/myPhrase/ ) {$x=~s!\\\\!/!g};sprintf("\x22%s\x22",$x)}ge ' file
```

with the below inputs

```
$ cat ykdvd.txt
"\\\\server\\dir\\myPhrase\\subdir"
"Don't change \\something me!"
Another line

$ perl -pe ' s{"(.+)?"}{$x=$1; if($x=~m/myPhrase/ ) {$x=~s!\\\\!/!g};sprintf("\x22%s\x22",$x)}ge ' ykdvd.txt
"//server/dir/myPhrase/subdir"
"Don't change \\something me!"
Another line

$
```